# org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found Error Android API level 30

Tags: android, xerces, akamai

I am facing the following issue while including a 3PL(com.akamai:edgeauth:0.2.0 hosted on https://github.com/akamai/EdgeAuth-Token-Java):

```
java.lang.Error: r6.a: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
...
Caused by: r6.a: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
```

I understand the library is outdated and may be using this dependency. I checked and included the following dependencies in my project:

```
implementation ('com.akamai:edgeauth:0.2.0', {
    exclude group: 'xerces', module: 'xercesImpl'
})
implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.0'
implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
```

Still, I am facing this issue in android API level 30. Please help to resolve this for newer versions of android.